# RasaNLUHttpInterpreter: takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am using the RasaNLUHttpInterpreter as stated [here](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/rasa-core-0.9.4/autoapi/interpreter/index.html#interpreter.RasaNLUHttpInterpreter) to start my server. I give the class all the 4 parameters required (model-name, token, server-name, and project-name). However, I always get the error, that apparently I am handing over 5 arguments (what I don't really do).

The error occurred since I updated my Rasa-Core and NLU to the latest version. However, as in docs, I feel that I use the method correctly. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong or what's happening here?

Here is my run-server.py where I use the RasaNLUHttpInterpreter:

```
import os
from os import environ as env
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

from server import create_app
from rasa_core import utils
from rasa_core.interpreter import RasaNLUHttpInterpreter


utils.configure_colored_logging("DEBUG")

user_input_dir = "/app/nlu/" + env["RASA_NLU_PROJECT_NAME"] + "/user_input"
if not os.path.exists(user_input_dir):
    os.makedirs(user_input_dir)

nlu_interpreter = RasaNLUHttpInterpreter(
    'model_20190702-103405', None, 'http://rasa-nlu:5000', 'test_project')

app = create_app(
    model_directory = env["RASA_CORE_MODEL_PATH"],
    cors_origins="*",
    loglevel = "DEBUG",
    logfile = "./logs/rasa_core.log",
    interpreter = nlu_interpreter)

http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5005), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

I am using:
rasa_nlu~=0.15.1
rasa_core==0.14.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as already mentioned [here](https://forum.rasa.com/t/rasanluhttpinterpreter-takes-from-1-to-4-positional-arguments-but-5-were-given/12364/19) I have analyzed the problem in detail.

First of all, the method calls and the given link belong to a rasa version that is deprecated. After updating to the latest rasa version which splits up core and nlu, the project was refactored to fit the according documentation.

After rebuilding the bot with the exact same setup, no errors were thrown and the bot worked as expected.

We came to the conclusion that this must have been a particular problem on threxx's workstation.

If someone else might come to this point, he is welcome to post here such that we could help him.